org-babel: Pass flags when filtering source code blocks?
I'm currently using org-mode to make some beamer slides, where I'm generating some code blocks and results using org-bable. I'm currently using org-export-filter-src-block-functions to modify the exported code, adding things like \pause at the start of each line.
The problem is that I don't want the filter applied to every source block, just the ones I specify, and I'd like the filter to work differently on source blocks vs RESULTS blocks.
The functions in "org-export-filter-src-block-functions" are only given the text in the source code block, not any of the surrounding attributes or flags.
Is there a way to selectively apply a filter to a source code block, that will:

Let me see what flags/attributes the code block has, so I can apply the filter selectively
Let me see whether I'm in a source block or a results block, so I can filter differently based on that?


The filter does not do anything to #+RESULTS blocks, only to the source blocks. There is no filter set defined for results blocks.

There is a ton of info in the info argument to the filter function but I couldn't find anything that would identify which code block gave rise to a particular call of the function. They are processed from top to bottom, so you could do something gross like counting how many times the filter is called. But it seems harder than perhaps it should be (unless I'm missing something which is a distinct possibility).
